# How do I override the __str__() method of a single field without creating a node ModelField class?

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.9

I have the following Model class that represents my assets including the costs.

```
class Asset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Is there a way to override the `__str__()` method of `Asset.cost`?

My goal is to have the output of `cost` including the currency symbol while preserving the properties of an integer.

Examples:

```
obj.cost = 10.00

print(obj.cost) # should return $10.00
print(obj.cost + 10) # should still be possible
                     # and should return 20.00 (without currency symbol,
                     #                          because it is a regular integer now)
```

Comment: Note that `obj.cost` is just a [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) instance. It's not advisable to override the `__str__` method on the built-in `Decimal` class. You can use a utility function to print the decimal with a currency symbol.

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently not possible. `__str__` is the method that belongs to class `Asset`, but if you want to print `object.cost`, you were trying to show the string representation of the **field** `cost`. `__str__` can only affect the output of objects of model `Asset` but not individual fields.

Secondly, `object.cost + 10` doesn't add `10` to `object.cost`, you were just printing the result of two integer additions, but you didn't save the result to a variable nor assigned to `object.cost`, so `__str__` can't do anything.

You need a util function to do this, which I assume it's kind of trivial. That function should be in the class `Asset` unless you have other situations to print currency. In which cases the util should be an independent function.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method `display_cost` that you can then call when you need the preceding dollar sign.

```
def display_cost(self):
    return "${amount}".format(amount=self.cost)


obj.cost = 10.00
obj.save()
obj.display_cost() # >> "$10.00"
```

This way you'd still be preserving the properties of an integer by not changing your Asset.cost field but using a function to wrap it whenever you need.